# How to join maps in Apache Spark and perform RDD operations on them?

Tags: sql, csv, apache-spark

I have been playing around with Apache Spark, firstly I learned PostgreSQL and I have a few queries that I need to run on Spark. I managed to run them as SQL Strings in Spark SQL, but now I have to perform RDD operations in order to get the same results. I load my data from csv to map. Now I have to select specific columns in those maps, but I do not know how to join them (multiple maps/csv files). Second question I have is how to best perform RDD operations in order to get the same results from postgresql queries?

I tried reading on RDD operations, which include transformations and amongst them is join, but it is not letting me join maps.

One of the queries:

```
SELECT Tournaments.TYear,Countries.Name,Max(Matches.MatchDate) - 
Min(Matches.MatchDate) AS LENGTH
FROM Tournaments,Countries,Hosts,Teams,Matches
WHERE Tournaments.TYear = Hosts.TYear AND Countries.Cid = Hosts.Cid 
AND (Teams.Tid = Matches.HomeTid OR Teams.Tid = Matches.VisitTid) AND 
date_part('year', Matches.MatchDate)::text LIKE (Tournaments.TYear || 
'%')
GROUP BY Tournaments.TYear,Countries.Name
ORDER BY LENGTH,Tournaments.TYear ASC
```

Comment: Are you running those queries on Postgres or Apache Spark?

Comment: The query example I wrote is for Postgres, but I need to have the same one using only RDD operations.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you are trying to join "maps", are you referring to RDDs? Spark data is contained within RDDs, which can be transformed using map transformations. What is the reason you are unable to use Spark SQL? Using Spark SQL to perform this query on DataFrames in Spark would be the easiest translation from this query to what you want to achieve using Spark.

Comment: As I wrote in my post, I already used Spark SQL successfully, but now I have to perform RDD operations in order to get the same result.

Comment: I was asking for the reason you’re unable to use Spark SQL so I can more accurately tailor to your problem.

Comment: It is a task, no particular reason.